# Error with Views + VBO

Tags: drupal-views

I want to give organizations administrators the ability to update events or memberships contributions payments by check, without having to do an Advanced Search based upon pending statuses to such or such event or membership.

As far as I know, I cannot store such searches to replay them.

So, I am testing an approach using Views with a VBO operation field which enables Contribution edition : enclosed screen capture[image]

When I tick a line of the report, and then confirm the item (Edit Contribution) I get the following error :

*Une erreur HTTP AJAX s'est produite. 
Code de statut HTTP : 200 Informations de débogage ci-dessous. Chemin : /batch?id=6940&op=do StatusText: OK 
ResponseText : 
Add CiviCRM Contribution | BAPA (Paroisse de La Celle Saint Cloud) 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/modules/system/system.base.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/modules/system/system.menus.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/modules/system/system.messages.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/modules/system/system.theme.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/modules/contextual/contextual.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/modules/comment/comment.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/modules/field/theme/field.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/modules/node/node.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/modules/search/search.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/modules/user/user.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/css/ckeditor.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/sites/all/modules/advuser/css/advuser.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/sites/all/modules/l10n_client/l10n_client.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/modules/shortcut/shortcut.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/modules/toolbar/toolbar.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/themes/bartik/css/layout.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/themes/bartik/css/style.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/sites/default/files/color/bartik-8a90baaf/colors.css?ook5dq"); 
@import url("https://xxxx.com/themes/bartik/css/print.css?ook5dq");
...*

Depending upon context, ?ook5dq can change to ?oonnv5 (and maybe others (?))

I am not familiar with Views ; Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

if i was testing this, i would

a/ confirm vbo works for you for normal drupal process (eg node based view, can you use vbo to publish/unpublish), then if that works,

b/ set up a civi contact based VBO that uses other entities. if it fails,

c/ export the view and attach here so someone else can confirm if it is an issue on their set up

Comment: Thank you Pete ; I have just tested b/ : it works OK to e.g. "Add Contacts to Group" ; but I get the same error if I select "Edit Contact" (though the targetted Contact is correct in the error message). By the way, do you know where I can find some user documentation about VBO ?

Comment: FYI, my View only contains Contact ID, LastName, First Name, and Bulk Operation Field

Comment: One thing could help me a lot (I think) : an simple example of View with Edit Contact BO working and a screen shot of how BO field is parameterized.

Comment: I don't think any documentation is done. If Fuzion did the original work for this (not sure but I know Eileen had a big hand in it) it was likely done in a scramble to do something that was needed by a client that we never really had budget to do or document etc. I will try and take a look later this week.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pete. BTW, what are tokens for and how can they be used (in the BO field parameterization) ?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. Tokens are using a bit of code that will be replaced when used in contect, eg Dear {first.name}, will be replaced with Dear Peter, in my case, and Dear Jackques-Marie in your case

Comment: Thank you Pete, I know what tokens are, generally speaking, but I did not understand the way they are used in VBO. I have made some testing and I think I begin to understand (thanks to your https://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/confirming-attendees-door-another-use-entity-and-vbo). But everything is not yet clear : for instance, when I set contribution_status_id to "1", it works, but when I set it to "2", I have an AJAX error. I have to investigate a bit further, but I am not yet sure that VBO can answer my original problem.